# A confusion about chromecast discover

Tags: chromecast, mdns

When I click google cast icon in my chrome browser, it will try to discover whether there is an available chromecast around my pc.
If yes, then it will recognize it (assume that chromecast has already been set and connect to the same router which my pc is connected to).

My first confusion is, during this course, does my pc ever connect to chromecast's own wifi signal? Or they ONLY talk via my router?

My second confusion comes from a test:

```
  I set 2 routers: router_A on top;router_B connects to LAN port of router_A;
  My pc also connects to router_A;
  chromecast dongle connects to router_B;
  multicast/upnp of router B is enabled, firewall on router_B is disabled.
```

My pc cannot find chromecast in this situation. I'm confused and I think it should work since router_B obtains ip/gateway from router_A.

The third confusion is when I swapped my pc and chromcast, to let my pc connect to router_B, and chromecast connect to router_A, my pc found the chormcast......

Answer (score 0):

After Chormecast is set up with a wifi network, it is discovered through mDNS. For (2) and (3), since discovery is done through multicast/mDNS, you need to read on that topic and look at the configuration settings of your routers to see how you can set things up to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks~. Does the discover use port 5353? May i sniffer packets with tools like wireshark? --(I ever read some post talked about port 1900, but I don't exactly remember what that port was used for。。。）